# What should I do to choose a directory where the computer deems to be valid?

Tags: terminal

I am trying to install DISLIN library into to my macbook.I am at this point of the installation where an error(?) occured.

> d) Choose a directory in the file structure where DISLIN should be
>      installed and define the environment variable DISLIN with it:
>
> For example:   export DISLIN/$HOME/dislin

```
    Gandos-MacBook-Air:dislin-10.6 gando$ export dislin$HOME/dislin
    -bash: export: `dislin/Users/gando/dislin': not a valid identifier
```

Answer (score 8):

This should very likely read

```
export DISLIN=$HOME/dislin
```

with an `=` instead of a `/`. It's probably a typo, notify whoever wrote this documentation.